# Office 365 app & Angular 2 routing only works the first time

Tags: typescript, angular, office365, angular2-routing, office365-apps

I am trying to get Angular 2 routing to work with Office App. It only works the first time and after that, it stops working. I have managed to get the same code to work with ASP.Net5 but not with Office Apps.

I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Update 2 and Office 2016. I have attached the solution to reproduce the issue.

Link to the solution files: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1D346F6F0769D8C!991&authkey=!AGQlHsr70YHepv4&ithint=file%2crar

Steps to reproduce:

1) Compile and run the solution.

2) Click on Page 1.

3) It will navigate to Page 1.

4) Click on Page 2 and nothing happens.

Repeat the above with Page 2 first and it will show Page 2. Somehow, it stops working after the first time. I can't figure out what I am doing incorrectly as I can't get such a simple example to work.

Thanks in advance!

Edit #1:
I added the following and managed to get routing to work but only by using the **navigateByUrl** method.

The app.component.html is now:

```
<nav>
    <a [routerLink]="['PageOne']">Page 1</a>
    <a [routerLink]="['PageTwo']">Page 2</a>
</nav>
<button (click)="pOne()">Page 1</button>
<button (click)="pTwo()">Page 2</button>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And the app.component.ts is now:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from "angular2/router";
import {PageOneComponent} from "./pageone.component";
import {PageTwoComponent} from "./pagetwo.component";

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl: "app/app.component.html",
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@RouteConfig([
    {
        path: "/pageone",
        name: "PageOne",
        component: PageOneComponent
    },
    {
        path: "/pagetwo",
        name: "PageTwo",
        component: PageTwoComponent
    }
])
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private _router: Router) { }

    public pOne() {
        //this._router.navigate(["PageOne"]);
        this._router.navigateByUrl("/pageone", true);
    }

    public pTwo() {
        //this._router.navigate(["PageTwo"]);
        this._router.navigateByUrl("/pagetwo", true);
    }
}
```

As mentioned above, the **navigate** method will only work the first time and the **navigateByUrl** method will only work if you set **_skipLocationChange** to true.

Edit #2:
Bootstrap is:

```
///<reference path="../../../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>
//import {enableProdMode} from 'angular2/core'
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';

//enableProdMode();
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);
```

Home.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="../../App/Home/"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
    <title></title>

    <script src="../../Scripts/node_modules/es6-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/node_modules/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/node_modules/shims_for_IE.js"></script>

    <script src="../../Scripts/node_modules/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/node_modules/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/node_modules/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/node_modules/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/node_modules/http.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/node_modules/router.dev.js"></script>


    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link href="../../Content/Office.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- To enable offline debugging using a local reference to Office.js, use: -->
    <!-- <script src="../../Scripts/Office/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
    <!-- <script src="../../Scripts/Office/1/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->

    <!--<link href="../App.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="../App.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link href="Home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="Home.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
        Office.initialize = function(reason) {
            System.config({
                meta: {
                    "./*": { scriptLoad: true }
                },
                packages: {
                    app: {
                        format: 'register',
                        defaultExtension: 'js'
                    }
                }
            });
            System.import('app/main')
                .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content-header">
        <div class="padding">
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content-main">
        <div class="padding">
            <my-app>LOADING.........</my-app>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How does your `bootstrap(...)` look like?

Comment: I have added the bootstrap code above.

Comment: Is `HashLocationStrategy` an option? I don't know the constraints of Office 365 apps. That it works with `_skipLocationChange` is a hint that `pushState` might not be supported. This would mean that you need to use a custom `LocationStrategy` implementation that doesn't use `pushState` (which `HashLocationStrategy` also uses. The code is not complicated https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/platform/browser/location/hash_location_strategy.ts. You would need to create an altrenative implementation that uses for example an array instead of `pushState`.

Comment: Will give that a go and post an update. Thanks!

Comment: I'd try to switch to `HashLocationStrategy` first. If that doesn't work I'd try the custom `LocationStrategy`

Comment: Any ideas why URL works?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "URL". You wrote `_skipLocationChange` works, which as far as I know skips updating the browser history (calling `pushState`).

Comment: As in why Navigate does not work but NavigateByUrl actually works.

Comment: Can you clarify a couple of things for me? 1) What version of Outlook are you using, or are you using Outlook Web? 2) Without skipLocationChange, can you hover over your nav links that don't work, and see if there are hash parameters (e.g., #_xdm_info) that you don't recognize in the link?

Comment: 1) I am not sure what has it got to do with Outlook but the app is an Excel app and I am using Excel 2016. 2) When I did a right click copy shortcut, I get https://localhost:44354/App/Home/pagetwo which is what I expected.

Comment: I have also tried the HashLocationStrategy and it does not work. It only works the first time as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in a later version of Angular 2.